# Sticky Sections are jerk (flicker) on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a web page with multiple sticky sections & The page is working fine when the content is full in document. But I'm getting an issue with empty or minimal content in the document in that case the page is jerking on scrolling.

I'm sharing my web page code.

Page with scroll (jerk) issue.
https://codepen.io/syedrafeeq/full/PoPywVe

**Here is page demo.(Full Content)**

```js
 $(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 40) {
   $('.nav-wrapper').addClass("fixed-header");
   $(".left-side-menu").addClass("fixed-sidebar");
   $(".right-side-menu").addClass("fixed-sidebar");
  }
  else {
   $('.nav-wrapper').removeClass("fixed-header");
   $(".left-side-menu").removeClass("fixed-sidebar");
   $(".right-side-menu").removeClass("fixed-sidebar");
  }
 });
```

```css
@import url("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap');

html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

h1{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 35px 0;
}

h2{font-size: 1.3rem; font-weight: bold; color: #3d464d;}

ul{list-style: none;}

header{
    background: #d4e0ed; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d4e0ed 0%, #b9cee8 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d4e0ed 0%,#b9cee8 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d4e0ed 0%,#b9cee8 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d4e0ed', endColorstr='#b9cee8',GradientType=0 );    
}
header h1{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.pro-steps{background: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #d5dde6;}

.pro-steps ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.pro-steps .selected{
    background: #5082BE; 
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.pro-steps ul li:hover{color: #5082BE;}
.pro-steps ul li.selected:hover{color: #fff;}
.pro-steps ul li.selected :before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 27px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 27px solid transparent;
}

.pro-steps ul li.selected :after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 27px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #5082BE;
    border-bottom: 27px solid transparent;
}

.pro-steps ul li:first-child.selected label:before{border-left: 0;}

.pro-steps .selected span{
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 27px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #5082BE;
    border-bottom: 27px solid transparent;
}
.btn-next img{margin-left: 5px;}
.btn-back img{margin-right: 5px;}
.pro-steps ul li{
    position: relative;
    padding: 16px 23px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3d464d;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pro-steps ul li:first-child{padding-left: 0;}
.pro-steps ul li:first-child.selected{padding-left: 10px;}

.pro-steps ul li:before{
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    height: 14px;
    background: #5082BE;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: -4px;
    top: 14px;
}

.pro-steps ul li:after{
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    height: 14px;
    background: #5082BE;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: -4px;
    top: 26px;
}

.pro-steps ul li img { vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 5px; }
.pro-steps ul li label { margin-bottom: 0; cursor: pointer; }

.content-body{
    padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.fixed-sidebar{
 position: fixed;
 top: 140px;
 width: 175px;
}

.default-height {
 top: 90px;
}
.static-menu .list-group-item {
 padding: 0.5rem 1rem; 
}

/*----- Header Nav -----*/
.message-wrap {
 color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 30px;
}
.inner-section {
 float: left;
 line-height: 30px;
}
.header-nav {
 background-color: #8d9fb5;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 5px 0;
}

.welcome-message {
 display: inline-block;
}

.quote-number {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.fixed-header{
    background-color:#fff !important;
    padding: 0px  !important;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
 z-index:888;
    width: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    
}

.inside-header {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
 padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
}
.inside-header  a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
}
.list-group-item {
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 0.5rem 1rem; 
}
.action-title {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.main-wrap {
 height: 100%;
}
.main-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    /* margin-bottom: -50px; */
}

.main-wrapper {
 position: relative;
}

.mid-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 /* background-color: #fff000; */
}

.mid-content {
 padding: 0 0 20px;
}

footer{
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f3f6f8;
    padding: 10px 0; 
    border-top: 1px solid #e1e8ed;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="main-wrapper" id="mainWrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row header">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1>Header Section</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
   <div class="header-nav">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="message-wrap">
      <div class="inner-section">
       <div class="welcome-message">Welcome Message</div>
      </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
   
  <div class="pro-steps">
    <div class="container">
     <ul>
      <li>       
       <label>Home</label>
      </li>
      <li>       
       <label>About</label>
      </li>
      <li>       
       <label>Services</label>
      </li>
      <li>       
       <label>Products</label>
      </li>
      <li>
       
       <label>Products</label>
      </li>
      <li>       
       <label>Products</label>
      </li>
      <li>       
       <label>Products</label>
      </li>
      <li>       
       <label>Products</label>
      </li>
      <li>       
       <label>Products</label>
      </li>
      <li>       
       <label>Products</label>
      </li>
      <li>       
       <label>Products</label>
      </li>      
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="light-box" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="container main-wrap">
   <div class="row content-body rateSummary">
    <div class="col-lg-2 pr-0">
     <div class="left-side-menu">
      <div class="list-group mb-4">
       <a class="list-group-item text-center"><h6 class="action-title">Left Sidebar</h6></a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 1</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 2</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 3</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 4</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 5</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 6</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 7</a> 
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 8</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 9</a>
      </div>        
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class=" mid-wrapper">
       <div class="mid-content">
       
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed dictum sagittis dolor. Maecenas volutpat, dui a tincidunt lacinia, leo purus posuere lacus, vel consectetur libero ex sed quam. Nulla facilisi. Nam mollis dictum mi in dictum. Sed ut convallis nulla. Proin consectetur arcu leo, eget rhoncus sapien malesuada a. Donec finibus faucibus convallis. Integer varius iaculis diam eget fermentum. Fusce iaculis ipsum quis ligula iaculis, non laoreet lectus tincidunt. Ut pellentesque sit amet quam sed tempor. Donec laoreet justo eleifend lacus placerat efficitur. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Cras tincidunt vitae tortor aliquam tempor. Fusce non dui metus.</p>

        <p>Quisque blandit libero nec diam tristique, vel tristique elit egestas. Nulla justo libero, auctor sed volutpat vel, varius ac lorem. Ut vel orci a erat porta condimentum facilisis in lorem. Ut eu eros nisl. Nunc ac posuere enim. Vivamus accumsan urna risus, in accumsan sem tristique vitae. Praesent interdum ante et nibh laoreet lacinia. Pellentesque id lacus ac odio suscipit imperdiet vel egestas nibh. Duis quis quam at diam accumsan interdum. Morbi mollis, leo ut congue blandit, dui arcu scelerisque mi, eu tempus diam metus in odio. Cras lacus eros, aliquet in sagittis a, molestie in erat. Nullam vestibulum placerat risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec gravida interdum urna, nec dignissim metus.</p>


        <p>Aenean eu elit nec enim rutrum mollis. Mauris a ipsum sed lacus vehicula consectetur in vel eros. Nulla tempus ligula non efficitur hendrerit. Cras at ex semper, ultricies metus sed, semper est. Maecenas libero neque, semper eu vestibulum a, consectetur eu enim. Quisque at magna et risus pretium finibus. Nunc a egestas eros. Ut ac ligula dui. Sed ultrices ipsum luctus nunc pulvinar, sit amet tristique elit rhoncus. Donec pulvinar nulla id leo interdum rutrum.</p>


        <p>Nunc commodo mauris lectus, eu sollicitudin sem tempor sed. Proin scelerisque lacus vitae efficitur dignissim. In quis eleifend lectus. Sed scelerisque est risus, id sagittis justo rhoncus sit amet. Praesent viverra, urna ac posuere euismod, massa metus blandit est, eget porttitor purus lacus id nibh. Donec faucibus tellus ante, eu porttitor ante suscipit vel. Integer vel est non libero dignissim elementum non ac nisi. Praesent tincidunt enim id felis interdum facilisis. Donec fringilla a leo efficitur tempor. Phasellus non ligula nec nisl cursus volutpat ac sed augue.</p>


        <p>Cras facilisis felis eros, eget dignissim leo ultrices molestie. Aenean et lorem nisl. Nulla pretium ex enim, eu bibendum neque efficitur luctus. Nunc eget tempus quam. Vestibulum eu hendrerit quam. Maecenas pulvinar felis vitae dolor volutpat, nec interdum ligula commodo. Nullam sed mauris fringilla lacus suscipit molestie. Pellentesque lobortis a dolor non venenatis. Praesent egestas ipsum risus, eget finibus augue viverra in. Etiam quis sem eget nisi eleifend eleifend. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

        
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 pl-0">
     <div class="right-side-menu">
      <div class="list-group mb-4">
       <a class="list-group-item text-center"><h6 class="action-title">Right Sidebar</h6></a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 1</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 2</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 3</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 4</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 5</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 6</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 7</a> 
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 8</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Demo Link 9</a>
      </div>        
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer clearfix">
   <div class="container"> <strong>Terms & Privacy</strong></div>
  </footer>
 </div>
```

Page with full content demo: 
https://codepen.io/syedrafeeq/full/ZEbqYqg

Comment: Please remove the image and put the actual HTML in the snippet I made you so we can see the problem happening

Comment: Okay. I will update it shortly. Actually It's dynamic web page. I don't have HTML with me.

Comment: In which case just copy the relevant parts of the source of what's dynamically generated.

Comment: I need to set minimum hight to "content body" for each page. If I remove this height. The empty content  or low content page are jerking on scroll .content-body {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    /* min-height: 600px; */
}

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: I have updated my question with HTML with demo content.

Comment: Read [w3schools: HTML DOM scrollTop Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp). Your JS tests `if >40 then ....`. As at some point `>40` remains `true` when scrolling, so you keep adding classes. You need to check if the classes have been added already...

Comment: Hi @Rene van der Lende, I will try your solution once & let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Making my comment into an answer:

For reference info, read [w3schools: HTML DOM scrollTop Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp).

Your Javascript tests `if >40 then add classes`. As at some point `>40` remains `true` when scrolling, so you keep adding classes even when you are at the bottom, which causes the flicker.

You need to check if the classes have been added already and if there is still document left to scroll.

BTW: why don't you just `toggle()` the classes? [w3schools: How TO - Toggle Class](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)